# vfork() calls SYS_vfork but fork() calls SYS_clone?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, glibc, ltrace

After running `ltrace -S` on two programs that were compiled by `gcc` (version 5.4.0), one that calls `vfork()` and one that calls `fork()`, I find that `vfork()` calls `SYS_vfork` whilst `fork()` calls `SYS_clone`.  I could not find any information about this specific behavior anywhere (some sources say each of `fork()`, `vfork()` and `clone()` are implemented by the correspondingly named `sys_` call, whilst other sources say all three calls are implemented using `sys_clone`).

Source code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{
        int pid;
        pid=vfork();
}
```

Output from `ltrace -S`:

```
...
__libc_start_main([some stuff here] <unfinished ...>
vfork([more stuff] <unfinished ...>
SYS_vfork([more stuff])
--- SIGCHLD (Child exited) ---
```

Is there a reason libc uses `SYS_vfork` for `vfork()`
but doesn't use `SYS_fork` for `fork()`? 
I’ve read [Thomas Nyman’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87551/23408#87684) to
[Which file in kernel specifies fork(), vfork()…
to use sys_clone() system call](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87551/23408), which says:

> `vfork()` in turn is implemented via a separate `CLONE_VFORK` flag, which will cause the parent process to sleep until the child process wakes it via a signal. The child will be the sole thread of execution in the parent's namespace, until it calls `exec()` or exits. The child is not allowed to write to the memory. The corresponding `clone()` call could be as follows:
>
> `clone(CLONE_VFORK | CLONE_VM | SIGCHLD, 0)`

This seems to be at odds with what I've observed of the output of `ltrace -S`.

Did I mess something up or did the glibc writers deliberately choose to implement `vfork()` using `SYS_vfork` instead of `SYS_clone` for a reason? Is this considered something that could change at any time or can we rely on it?

Comment: Mostly good info can be read in "Linux Kernel Development" 3rd edition by Robert Love in chapter 3 "Maintenance of processes". This chapter has detailed info.

Comment: Your example invokes undefined behaviour because the forked child neither calls `_exit()` nor `exec()`. For example, on a Fedora 27 box it just segfaults. See https://gist.github.com/gsauthof/d562355dc8e220c9cf8d2faa921388d0 for a more complete minimal example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Did I mess something up or did the glibc writers deliberately choose to implement vfork() using SYS_vfork instead of SYS_clone for a reason?

Historically, I think it’s more likely that this is simply a result of `vfork` not needing to be changed. Both `vfork` and `fork` initially used the equivalent system calls. When NPTL threading was implemented, [the `fork` implementation was changed to use `clone`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=commit;h=76a50749f7af5935ba3739e815aa6a16ae4440d1), because [the C library needs to reset the thread id](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37165339/4500798). `vfork` doesn’t need to worry about threads, because it’s only intended for use with `execve` (which is going to reset all that state anyway), so it was left untouched.

[The NPTL design paper](https://www.akkadia.org/drepper/nptl-design.pdf) explains why the `fork` system call isn’t sufficient to implement the `fork` library call when threads are liable to be used:

> To implement the `fork` function without memory leaks it is necessary that the memory used for stacks and other internal information of all threads except the thread calling `fork` is reclaimed. The kernel cannot help in this situation.

---

> Is this considered something that could change at any time or can we rely on it?

Since you’re using the C library to fork, you can only rely on the C library providing the behaviour documented in the APIs; you can’t rely on a specific implementation. You shouldn’t rely on `vfork(3)` using the `vfork(2)` system call instead of `clone(2)`, nor should you rely on `fork(3)` using `clone(2)` instead of `fork(2)`. Note that the system calls which are used can vary from one architecture to another...

If you really need to rely on specific system calls, you should use those directly and forego the C library wrappers.

Answer (score 2):

[`man 2 fork`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html):

> **C library/kernel differences**
>          Since version 2.3.3, rather than invoking the  kernel's  fork()  system
>          call,  the  glibc  fork()  wrapper that is provided as part of the NPTL
>          threading implementation invokes clone(2) with flags that  provide  the
>          same  effect  as  the  traditional  system  call.  (A call to fork() is
>          equivalent to a call to clone(2) specifying  flags  as  just  SIGCHLD.)
>          The  glibc wrapper invokes any fork handlers that have been established
>          using pthread_atfork(3).

Comment: Hum yes I answered a bit too fast, there are two questions and I addressed only one